# browserify package: how to expose library inside window object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundle, browserify, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to bundle my library into a `.js` file that would be loadable from a script tag. I want to have my library available under a variable in the browser console (in other words, I want to export it into `window` object). How can I do it in browserify?

This is my existing grunt-browserify config:

```
browserify: {
  options: {
    watch: "on",
    banner: "<%= banner %>",
    browserifyOptions: {
      insertGlobalVars: "on",
      noBuiltins: true,
      detectGlobals: false
    }
  },
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dist/json-schema-faker.js': ['lib/index.js']
    }
  }
```

Currently I can't use my bundled library from **outside** the package.

I know that browserify supports [External requires](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires), but instead of

```
var jsf = require('json-schema-faker');
jsf.doSomething();
```

I would prefer to do:

```
jsf.doSomething();
```

directly (so that assigning `jsf` to `window` would be automatic). How to do that, what are the possibilities of browserify in that matter?

Answer (score -1):

In browserified code, you have access to the normal `window` variable, and it's also aliased as `global` for compatibility with Node. So you can just add this to the end of your code:

```
global.jsf = jsf;
```

if you'd rather not have `json-schema-faker` always export itself, wrap it in another module that re-exports `jsf` and also attaches it to `global`.

Comment: I don't want to include code that attaches my lib into `global`, since it would affect node.js environment as well. Actually, it would just affect the library itself. So far I think that `standalone` option is a better solution.